# In Firefox only, alert box not reached or stopped after 'location.href = ..' redirect

Tags: javascript, firefox

In my JavaScript code I need to perform 2 sequential `location.href=..` redirects, with an alert box stop in the middle.

The below works in Chrome and IE, but **does not work in Firefox**. In FF only, the flow never stops to display the alert box and wait for a user response, it goes straight to the 2nd redirect.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    location.href = 'https://authdev.org.gov/agent/smlogoutredirector.asp?TARGET=https://www.org.gov';
    alert("You will be logged out now.");
    location.href = 'https://someotherurl.gov/action/';
});
</script>
```

Comment: you are hitting pretty much undefined or browser-specfic implementation details that should not be relyed on

Comment: You can not navigate to another page and run code after that.... What you want to do should not even work in any browser